# Improvements of migrating the Brave Basic Attention Token (BAT) from Ethereum to EOS?

Tags: ethereum

The brave browser uses the BAT token for its "Basic Attention Token" Ecosystem to fuction. What advantages would migrating that BAT ecosystem from Ethereum to EOS would have? And what would some pitfalls be?

Comment: Would it be better to make BAT work on EOS or make a fork?